# How to create an "external" 404 route in React router 4, when using nested routing?

Tags: reactjs, routes

I'm trying to create a 404 route in React router 4. The thing is, that my main routing page renders a component i call "container", in which all standard views are rendered. Looks something like that:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
 <Router history={history}>
   <div>
     <Header></Header>
     <Switch>
       <Route path="/" component={Container}  />
       <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
     </Switch>
   </div>
</Router>
);
```

Then the Container:

```
const Container = (props) => (
  <div>
      <Switch>       
          <Route path="/" component={DashboardPage} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/Test" component={Test} />
      </Switch>       
  </div>
 );
```

The idea is, to completely separate the 404 page from the container. With the current setup, the 404 page doesn't even get rendered. **If i put this route within the switch of the container**, it will be rendered in case of a 404, but it would be sitting inside the container of course.

What would be the way to completely separate it from the container?

Comment: Change your route to `<Route path="/" exact component={Container}  />`.

Comment: Tried it. i will render the 404 on every route, besides "/"

Comment: Add another route for `<Redirect to="/404" />` at the end which should redirect to a 404 component if no route matches. Replace '/404' with link to your 404 page.

Comment: Care to upvote the answer